# After retrieving data from a table, I am trying to condense a list of dictionaries to unique key values for "platform" with sum of "global sales"

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Below is code I'm running in my controller file for an asp.net application for a LINQ query.

var platformTotalSales = _context.VideoGames.Select(vg => new { vg.Platform, vg.GlobalSales });

result:

[
{
"platform": "DS",
"globalSales": 24.76
},
{
"platform": "X360",
"globalSales": 13.73
},
{
"platform": "PS3",
"globalSales": 21.4
},
{
"platform": "PS3",
"globalSales": 12.73
},
{
"platform": "Wii",
"globalSales": 28.62
},
{
"platform": "GBA",
"globalSales": 15.85
},
{
"platform": "DS",
"globalSales": 23.42
},
{
"platform": "DS",
"globalSales": 12.27
}
]

The list is much longer.  Looking to make key values unique for "platform" and add the total in global sales for each "platform".

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        
        var data = new Model[]{
        new Model("a",100),
        new Model("a",200),
        new Model("b",100)
        };
        
        
        var result = data.GroupBy(m=>m.Platform).ToDictionary(g=>g.Key,g=>g.Sum(m=>m.GlobalSales));
        
        // Writes 300
        Console.WriteLine(result["a"]); 
        // Writes 100
        Console.WriteLine(result["b"]);
    }
}

public class Model 
{
    
    public Model(string platform, int globalSales)
    {
        Platform = platform;
        GlobalSales = globalSales;
    }
    public string Platform {get;}
    
    public int GlobalSales {get;}
}
```

**UPDATE**
If you are using asp.net this probably won't work, but will work in asp.net core.
The example above works. To run go [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/), switch the Compiler (left) to .NET 6 and paste the code.

In this example, model is the class (or interface) that contains the properties (platform and global sales) from your example.

To apply this in your code you need to do it this way:

```
var platformTotalSales = _context.VideoGames.GroupBy(m=>m.Platform).ToDictionary(g=>g.Key,g=>g.Sum(m=>m.GlobalSales));
```

your original question asked for this:

> Looking to make key values unique for "platform" and add the total in >global sales for each "platform".

this code returns a dictionary, where each key is the platform and the value for each key is the total sales for that platform.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion. I tried plugging in this logic but it is throwing exceptions.

Comment: see update above